# vim - why is the cursor different in different terminals

Tags: terminal, cursor, console

I have vim 8.2 installed on my Debian machine and when I open it in a `gnome-terminal` it has a solid non-blinking box as a cursor.
But when I open a "pure" terminal with `ctrl+alt+F3` and open `vim` I get a blinking underscore as a cursor.
The same thing happens when I open `vim 8.2` on my `Arch Linux` machine that does not have a desktop environment.

Does someone know why that happens?
I mean it is the same `vim` installation. Is `gnome-terminal` opening a graphical form of vim? `gvim`? That would be strange because it is not really graphical as it is all in a terminal and I can't use a mouse in `gnome-terminal`...

Also using commands like these to change the cursor don't do anything in a pure `linux` terminal:

```
:set guicursor=n-v-c:block-Cursor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you run Vim in a terminal emulator, it is the terminal emulator that controls the cursor shape and color.

   Since you are using different terminal emulators it shouldn't be surprising to have different cursor shapes or colors.

   Note that it is *possible* to affect the cursor's shape from within Vim but a) it is not done by default, and b) the exact way depends on your terminal emulator.
2. As its name and documentation suggest, `:help 'guicursor'` only affects the GUI version of Vim. Setting the option in the TUI version has no effect.